# Can i start my app with a class except MyApp class?

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

I'm working on a mobile app that requires a login page. I already coded the home page. And i want app to start with login page, not the page i coded. Is there a way to start the app with another class except myapp class ?

I tried to start `runApp(ClassThatIWant());` but seems like thats not working.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: VoiceHome(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what exception you are getting? As long as its a widget you can pass it in the runApp method.

Answer (score 0):

You always run MyApp(). You access your login by doing this:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: YourLoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

it is also common to use Routes, like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
       title: "My app name",
       routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => YourLoginPage(),
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => VoiceHome(),
        '/otherscreen': (BuildContext context) => OtherScreen(),
        '/etc': (BuildContext context) => EtcScreen(),

      },
    );
  }
}
```

and refer to it by doing:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
```

Comment: As long as its a widget you can pass it in the runApp method. It doesn't have to be necessarily MyApp.